# TypeError: x.y is not a function, when apparently it is

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing a strange behavior off of javascript yet again. I find this to be extremely illogical and confusing.

[image]

I probably did kind of a mess drawing over the picture but briefly, you see that `$$('h2')` is clearly an object which **has** a method `on`, or in javascript language a property `on` which turns out to be a function, however when I try to access that function I get a TypeError?

**MY QUESTION IS:** Why am I getting this error when obviously the object does have a property called `on` which is a function?

**EDIT:** Here's the `on` function

```
on: function(event, func) {
        this.node.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the object definition for `on`, is it possible that `on` is actually a wrapper for a host of event functions? If so, then try  `$$('h2').on.click(function () { ... });`?

Comment: What library is providing the `$$`?

Comment: @valverij I updated the question adding the `on` function

Comment: @RocketHazmat it is a little library I made myself to aid me in my ventures, since I'm not a big fan of using a 100kb library just so that I can walk around my `DOM` :D

Comment: The syntax had me confusing this with jquery.

Comment: `$$('h2')` does not have `on`. `$$('h2')[0]` does. `$$('h2')` appears to be either an array or a NodeList, judging from the leading `[` in your console output.

Comment: @apsillers oh crap! I tangled inside my own "logic". Thank you sir! You should definitely post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed the leading `[` in your console output. The object you're printing is an array whose *first element* has an `on` property.

You likely want `$$('h2')[0].on(...)` instead.